# Fastest place to farm gold

Tags: wildstar

What's the fastest way to farm gold in Wildstar?

I'm currently level 45 and have almost 4 platinum from questing, however I know there has to be a faster method that does not involve playing the auction house.

Comment: I'm not level 50 yet, but I've heard from a guildy that farming lv50 dailies should yield a cool 2-4 plat per day.

Comment: Actually the fastest way really is to control the auction house. But there is no one fits all method to do that.  But there are better ways to farm, those methods, should be used to control the auction house.

Comment: @Ramhound My question involves not controlling the auction house

Comment: You said.  "There has to be a faster way" but there isn't the fastest way is to control the auction house.  If you want a sucessful way to make gold there are alternatives but they are all slower then controlling the auction house.

Comment: @Ramhound One way, although not guaranteed, is to just watch the CX for idiots selling materials lower than vendor prices.  I've routinely bought up hundreds of leather, ore, and relics simply to dump it to a vendor.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have read on various websites, everyone generally agrees with Thebluefish' comment.

At level 50, every 75k exp. gets you an [Elder Gem](http://wildstar.gamepedia.com/Elder_Gem).
Once you've reached the Elder Gem cap for the day, all experience points you get will be converted into silver.

From what I've read it seems you can farm 60 gold to 80 gold per hour, given that you've found a good spot to farm.

Note: This information was gathered from players who reached level 50, meaning that it's speculation, but backed up pretty well.

Comment: Being lvl 50 for the past few weeks I would say you are pretty close to correct. 1-1.5p is a bit of a stretch I would say UNTIL Carbine comes out with more dailies. As it stands capped with elder gems and doing all the Crimson Badlands dailies yields roughly 50-70g. whcih is about 30-45 minutes of Gameplay solo. I could see that happening once they release strain and there are more dailies to do. Unless there is a spot to farm gold that I am unaware of outside of quests.

Comment: All right, I changed it to 60 to 80 gold, to account for the grinding you could do in the remaining time.

Comment: There is no daily cap for Elder Gems. There is only a weekly cap. Do you mean that you earn silver after you reach the weekly cap?

Comment: I've done speed running gold Malgrave Trails in 30 minutes which nets you around 1-2p an hour depending on drops.